# Get the value that user select in JSP and and pass the value to the java class (Struts2)

Tags: java, database, jsp, struts2

I use Struts2 to create the function. Get the company's name and
business code from the database and make it to dropdown list. user
 have to select company's name, business code after that I want to send the value that user select to the java
 class.

selectCondition.jsp

```
<s:form action="ResultAction" method="post">
    <!-- Company Name -->
    <s:select name="company" list="companyList" listKey="companyId" 
        listValue="companyName" headerKey="0" headerValue="--- Company ---" label="Conpany"/>

    <!-- Business Code -->
    <s:select name="busiCode" list="busiCodeList" listKey="busiCodeId" 
        listValue="busiCodeName" headerKey="0" headerValue="--- Business Code ---" label="Business Code" />
</s:form>
```

SelectConditionAction.java

```
public class SelectConditionAction extends ActionSupport {  
    public String populate() {
    //Company
    companyList = new ArrayList<Company>();

    Statement statement = null;
    Connection conn = null;

    try {
        conn = DBUtils.getInstance().getConnection();
        statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT comp_id, comp_name FROM COMPANY ORDER BY comp_id ASC");

        while(rs.next()) {
            int index = 0;
            String companyName = "";
            Company company = new Company(index, companyName);
            index = rs.getInt("comp_id");
            companyName = rs.getString("comp_name");
            company.setCompanyId(index);
            company.setCompanyName(companyName);
            companyList.add(company);
            //System.out.println(index + " " + companyName);
        }
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();    

        try {
            conn.rollback();
        } catch(SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Business Code
    busiCodeList = new ArrayList<BusiCode>();

    Statement statement1 = null;
    Connection conn1 = null;

    try {
        conn1 = DBUtils.getInstance().getConnection();
        statement1 = conn1.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement1.executeQuery("SELECT busi_id, busi_name FROM Business ORDER BY busi_id ASC");

        while(rs.next()) {
            int index = 0;
            busiCode = "";
            BusiCode busicode = new BusiCode(index, busiCode);
            index = rs.getInt("busi_id");
            busiCode = rs.getString("busi_name");
            busicode.setBusiCodeId(index);
            busicode.setBusiCodeName(busiCode);
            busiCodeList.add(busicode);
            //System.out.println(index + " " + busiCode );
        }
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();    

        try {
            conn.rollback();
        } catch(SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return "populate";
}

public String execute() {
    return SUCCESS;
}

//Company
public String getCompany() {
    return company;
}

public void setCompany(String company) {
    this.company = company;
}

public ArrayList<Company> getCompanyList() {
    return companyList;
}

public void setCompanyList(ArrayList<Company> companyList) {
    this.companyList = companyList;
}

//Business Code
public String getBusiCode() {
    return busiCode;
}

public void setBusiCode(String busiCode) {
    this.busiCode = busiCode;
}

public ArrayList<BusiCode> getBusiCodeList() {
    return busiCodeList;
}

public void setBusiCodeList(ArrayList<BusiCode> busiCodeList) {
    this.busiCodeList = busiCodeList;
}
}
```

Example of company info

```
public class Company {

private int companyId;

private String companyName;

public Company(int companyId, String companyName) {
    this.companyId = companyId;
    this.companyName = companyName;
}

public int getCompanyId() {
    return companyId;
}
public void setCompanyId(int companyId) {
    this.companyId = companyId;
}
public String getCompanyName() {
    return companyName;
}
public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
    this.companyName = companyName;}
```

How can I get the value that user select in JSP and pass these value to the java class??

Comment: By submitting a form.

Comment: @AleksandrM   is it about the button?                                                        <s:submit value="Upload" action="uploadAction"/>
<s:submit value="Download" action="downloadAction"/>